# How to make admin form field readonly when edit

Tags: magento, admin

I am trying to make admin form field readonly using below code in `protected function _prepareForm()`.but it also make readonly when add new item.so i would like to make readonly when edit form.

```
readonly => true,
```

first time i should able to add text.

Comment: $id=$this->getRequest()->getParam('yourkey');                                        if($id){ edit form}else{'new'};

Answer (score 0):

You need to put above line based on condition like this,

```
$modelid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('YOUR KEY');

if($modelid > 0)
{
    readonly => true,
}
```